# How do I programmatically create kmltreeview folders and add placemarks in them?

Tags: c#, winforms, google-earth-plugin

Using the C# winforms-ge-plugin I am adding wi-fi hotspots to the ge globe and kmltreeview as the search protocol finds them.  I would like to group them based on cities using GPS coordinates.  The plan is to group each city as a folder but I am having trouble figuring out how to create folders in the kmltreeview.

Originally I tried this:

```
        var folder = kmlTreeView.CreateNode(FC.GEPluginCtrls.ApiType.KmlFolder);
        kmlTreeView.ParseKmlObject(folder);
```

but it didn't work.

I found some javascript based code on another forum but it isn't working either:

```
        var folder = ge1.createFolder("test");
        folder.getFeatures().setVisibility(true);
        folder.getFeatures().setOpen(true);

        var placemark = ge1.createPlacemark();
        folder.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);

        ge1.getFeatures().appendChild(folder);
```

Thanks for any help you can offer!
TC

Comment: What happens? Do you get a null object? Does it just not add the placemarks? If you could elaborate on what specifically happens it would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CreateNode` method takes any KmlObject as its parameter but you are passing it an enumerator of one of the types in the api.

Simply create the folder, then parse it in.

```
var folder = ge1.createFolder("test");
kmlTreeView.ParseKmlObject(folder);
```

To explain, the KmlTreeView doesn't generate or create KmlFolders, or 'kml' anything else - it just displays a view of KmlObjects loaded into it as a nodes in a hierarchy.

A 'folder', the thing that you actually see in the treeview, is just a representation of a KmlContainer, such as as KmlFolder or KmlDocument.

Another way to use the KmlTreeView is to simply load any kmlObject you load into the plugin directly into it as well. This would usually be the same object that is returned from a call to the GEWebBeowser's FetchKml method. For example.

```
   // load the plugin
    geWebBrowser1.LoadEmbededPlugin();

    // when the plug-in has loaded
    geWebBrowser1.PluginReady += (o, e) =>
    {
        // load the kml from the local server
        kmlTreeView1.SetBrowserInstance(e.ApiObject);
        geWebBrowser1.FetchKml("http://foo/some.kml");
    };

    // when the kml has loaded
    geWebBrowser1.KmlLoaded += (o, e) =>
    {
        // add the kml to the plugin and tree-view 
        geWebBrowser1.ParseKmlObject(e.ApiObject);
        kmlTreeView1.ParseKmlObject(e.ApiObject);
    };
```

This way the tree-view will synchronise with the display in the plug-in - so double-clicking on nodes in the tree-view will fly you to their location, etc.

Comment: Thanks Fraser. I use the documentation.xml file to search for fields, methods, etc. and createFolder is not in there.  Is there a better place for me to find these items?

Also, the folder is created but it does not have any text as a label (I had assumed it would be labeled 'test').  Where might I find a folder's attributes?  Thanks.

Comment: createFolder is a method of the GEPlugin object in the Google Earth Api - https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_g_e_plugin

Comment: 'test' is the folder id, use setName("whatever") to give it a name, this is what is displayed as the label for the node in the treeview.

Comment: I found the "setName" and "setDescription" functions in the GE API page.  I also found the createFolder there but I think it would have been difficult to find without knowing the name of it.  I've bookmarked that page now and will use it as my first stop when I need to find something.  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: No worries, if you go to the top level of the API reference - https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/ - you can clink on any type to see all of its members, as well as its inheritance chain. The is also a developers guide on working with object containers in kml - https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/containers